# Code selection bug in Visual Studio Color Theme Designer

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, user-interface, themes

So, long story short, I am trying to make a decent theme that would match my workmood. I am doing this through "[Microsoft Visual Studio Color Theme Designer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.ColorThemeDesigner)" in both ways (through GUI menu && by adjusting the .vstheme markdown code itself).

The problem is that whenever I select a string, or any code block, code selection occurs as if it were "under the code" rather than "above the code layer". Below you can see a couple of examples of how it should be and what happens.
[image]

I'd like to point out! I made sure that in the theme code, the 'background' parameter of each object is set to "00000000", which should leave the objects with only Foreground color.
[image]

When I select any block of code, I expect to see the selection above all the layers.

Like that:
[image]

P.S.
Also, just noticed that in the filetypes '.vstheme', '.json' everything works great, but somewhy in '.cs' filetype everything breaks down:
[image]

[link for a theme download & debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lxcalbxyprxd.venom777)
[link for a github to lurk for the code](https://github.com/lxcalbxy/Venom-EXTERNAL-VSTheme-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haha! I've solved it! I did a research on how does it work on all other well-known themes, so I found few GitHub `.vstheme` projects and compared the code.
All working themes have their object's background color set to `"CT_INVALID"` type.

Solution:

- **Go** to your `.vstheme` project and press `'View Code (F7)'`
  [image]
- **Go** to desired objects, change **background's type** of `"CT_RAW"` type to `"CT_INVALID"`
  [image]

Result:

- Done!
  [image]